# How to query this in LINQ? C#

Tags: c#, linq

Considering the following:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string fName, string lName)
    {
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
}

class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Person[] peopleArray = new Person[3]
        {
            new Person("John", "Smith"),
            new Person("Jim", "Johnson"),
            new Person("Sue", "Rabon"),
        };
        // select lastName from peopleArray where firstName like '%'J'%'
    }
}
```

Using LINQ, how can express this:

```
select lastName from peopleArray where firstName like '%'J'%'
```

I want to print the `lastnames` of all person having **"J"** in their `firstname`.
I find it hard to express it in LINQ. Help Please....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var query = from person in peopleArray 
            where person.firstName.Contains("J") 
            select person.lastName;

// or
var query = peopleArray.Where(p => p.firstName.Contains("J")).Select(p => p.lastName);

// use results, print to screen?
foreach (string lastName in query)
{
     Console.WriteLine(lastName);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but, How should I print it sir?

Comment: Can't edit the post for some reason, but if I could, I'd change `select person.firstName` to `select person.lastName`. Not a big deal of course.

Comment: @Rei, fixed, thanks. yonan, I added a simple foreach to iterate over the results.

Comment: missing a closing ) on the second one

Comment: It took me an hour, but I did not get the result I wanted. It's just a minute here to solve my problem. Thanks again :) (at least I tried, for nothing.. hehe)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> matchingLastNames = (from person in peopleArray 
                                  where person.firstName.Contains("J") 
                                  select person.lastName).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: It's OK to be explicit, but know that the `.ToList()` call does not need the `<string>` type parameter. Generic methods only need the type parameter if the compiler is unable to figure it out otherwise, such as if there are no parameters or alternately if there are multiple type candidates. `ToList()` has a parameter, which is the query result.

Comment: ahh you're right of course! Still learning how to express more elegantly and succinct in LINQ - your input is appreciated :-)

Answer (score -2):

I give you some advices.
1.learn what delegate is.
2.learn what lambda expression is.
3.learn extend methods.

if you learn these. you can write anything you like in linq.

Comment: Sounds like something one of my profs would say -- specifically, the intro Java instructor that thought that teaching about garbage collectors and JIT compilers was an excuse for not knowing any Java syntax himself.

Comment: sorry for that. that day i have a bad moon, so speak straigely